# How to create UIBackgroundModes keyin Info.plist for iOS5

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios5, plist

I believe it's no longer called UIBackgroundModes in iOS5 and xCode 4.2. What's the updated method in the info plist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple documentation shows that it's still supported under iOS5 with a couple of new iOS5-specific keys. Open Info.plist and type "UIBackgroundModes" into key field. That should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, entering the same is enough and it shows "Required Background modes"

Comment: what should we enter in value field to keep socket connection in background

Comment: in the iOS6 and forward, the field is "Required background modes".

Answer (score 10):

it is now called "Required background modes"